# Cordova fileTransfer mutliple files with promises

Tags: angularjs, cordova, promise, angular-promise

I´m trying to download about 100 images from a server. This works great.

```
        var promises = [];

        angular.forEach($scope.steps, function(value, key){
          promises.push(saveImageToPhone("http://192.168.178.250/w3/img/"+value.id+".jpg", value.id+".jpg"));
        });
        $q.all(promises).then(function(res) {
          console.log("all promises done");
        });
```

This calls the download function:

```
function saveImageToPhone(url, file) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var url = url;
    var filePath = cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory + "files/img/" +file;
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    var uri = encodeURI(url);

    fileTransfer.download(
      uri,
      filePath,
      function(entry) {
        console.log(entry);
        deferred.resolve();
      },
      function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        deferred.reject();
      },
      false,
      {
        headers: {
          "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
        }
      }
    );
    return deferred.promise;

  }
```

My thinkings are to call that `saveImageToPhone` function in that forEach loop and let the function return a promise. I´m pushing this promises to an array and wait for all promises in this array to resolve.

However the `console.log("all promises done")` is called before the first image is downloaded. I want this to call after ALL images has downloaded.

Could you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your promise handling is cause of your issue...try this:

```
function saveImageToPhone(url, file) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var url = url;
    var filePath = cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory + "files/img/" +file;
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    var uri = encodeURI(url);

    fileTransfer.download(
      uri,
      filePath,
      function(entry) {
        console.log(entry);

        // Change here
        deferred.resolve();
      },
      function(error) {
        console.log(error);

        // Change here
        deferred.reject();
      },
      false,
      {
        headers: {
          "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
        }
      }
    );

// Change here
return deferred.promise;

}
```

But FYI: The [File Tansfer Plugin from ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/) is already wrapping your `cordova plugins` into `angularjs` the right way. I would recommend to use it, because it is less error prone...

Comment: With the ngCordova version I would got the same plugin. Multiple file downloads are resulting in separate success/error/then handlers. But I need to listen for all promises resolving.

Comment: any errors? try to append a `.catch` block for errors additionally.

Comment: No errors. Not even in .catch. This is strange. So the logs in the success and error callback of the fileTransfer.download function is getting called whether the images exists or not. Nice. So the deferred should get rejected or resolved too. Looks like the $q.all is not detecting this.

Comment: The problem was the deferred.reject(). Some of the images were not present on the server, so the promise gets rejected and will never complete the $q.all. Thanks for your help!